# Apache certain vhosts getting stuck after random period of time

Tags: apache-2.4

I've come across something weird with Apache where a couple of vhosts stop responding after a couple of days/hours. The weird part is that the other vhosts keep working like they should.

Some information:

- The computer is running Windows Server 2008 R2 64x.
- All sites are running PHP.
- The stuck vhosts all have an SSL certificate installed. (this could be a link to the problem. Sites without SSL or with a completely different cert doesn't get stuck)
- Also the vhost with the same ServerName but without SSL cert gets stuck. These vhosts are also defined in the same file.
- The time after when this happens is random.
- Before the vhosts get stuck they respond normally and log normally (http200). After they get stuck, no logs at all, no access log, error log or anything.
- Network topology: unknown. It's a VPS.
- Yes. A windows setup with Apache. I know it sux but it's the choice of by boss which goes against all my recommendations for linux. Sorry :X

If I forgot some important information, please let me know. I'll add it.

Contents of the file with problematic vhosts. At time of being stuck all of the vhosts stop working (no logs, no response):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName download.websiteone.nl
    Redirect permanent / https://download.websiteone.nl/

    ErrorLog "C:\logs\download.websiteone.nl-reg-error.log"
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined
    CustomLog "C:\logs\download.websiteone.nl-reg-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName download.websitetwo.com
    Redirect permanent / https://download.websitetwo.com/

    ErrorLog "C:\logs\download.websitetwo.com-reg-error.log"
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined
    CustomLog "C:\logs\download.websitetwo.com-reg-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    Documentroot "C:\websiteone.NL\download.websiteone.nl"
    ServerName download.websiteone.nl
    Options FollowSymLinks
    ErrorLog "C:\logs\download.websiteone.nl-ssl-error.log"
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined
    CustomLog "C:\logs\download.websiteone.nl-ssl-access.log" combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all
    SSLCertificateFile C:\CERTIFICATES\websiteone\cert\websiteone.nl.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile C:\CERTIFICATES\websiteone\key\websiteone.nl.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile C:\CERTIFICATES\websiteone\cert\intermediate.cer
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
    Documentroot "C:\websiteone.NL\download.websiteone.nl"
    ServerName download.websitetwo.com
    Options FollowSymLinks
    ErrorLog "C:\logs\download.websitetwo.com-ssl-error.log"
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined
    CustomLog "C:\logs\download.websitetwo.com-ssl-access.log" combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all
    SSLCertificateFile C:\CERTIFICATES\websitetwo\cert\websitetwo.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile C:\CERTIFICATES\websitetwo\key\websitetwo.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile C:\CERTIFICATES\websitetwo\cert\intermediate.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks for your input!

Comment: I would start reviewing the php applications behind those that get stuck instead. Use mod-status with ExtendedStatus on, and enable some sort of logging for php. AFAIK php-fpm has a slowlog so you can check which requests take longer than expected.

Comment: Thing is, when they get stuck, they all get stuck at the same time - and these 4 to 5 vhosts are not using the same PHP files. And since the other PHP applications keep working, I doubt that is has anything to do with PHP. Or am I wring? Nontheless, thanks for your input.

Comment: Do you have any error logs from the Apache server? To see if you reach maxclients or similar, but it is easy to test. I bet you are probably using mod_php. Fire up a test server with the same exact settings except for the php parsing, for thatuse php-fpm instead, and then see if the httpd server keeps getting stuck having everything else configured the same way. [php parsing methods](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/php)

Comment: @ezra-s No errors about maxclients. No errors at all, that's the most strange. Should i switch to fpm instead to hopefiully fix this? Is that easy?

Comment: separating php processing from httpd to another server helps a lot pinpointing these problems, nothing is easy though.

Comment: Ever found a solution in this issue? We've the same problem. One of the VH just get's stuck after an undefined period of time. No errors in any log file (even in debug mode). Restarting httpd solves the problem but is very impractical.

Comment: @Inceddy I moved on from this setup, this server isn't up anymore and since it was more than over a year ago I don't know what I did (or if at all) to solve it - I think it was a task scheduler job to restart apache. The sites are now on Linux with Nginx and PHP-FPM. My server setup techniques were far from perfect those days.